# Combine contents of two QFormLayouts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QTabWidget` with two tabs. Depending on the settings chosen in the first tab, I dynamically change the contents of the second tab. The second tab contains a `QFormLayout` which can logically be split into a common part and a custom part. The common part does not depend on the settings in the first tab and the custom part does.

So, in Qt Designer I sketched a separate `.ui` file with the common part of the `QFormLayout` and two `.ui` files with custom parts. Then in code I do something like this:

```
customtab1 = uic.loadUi("commonFormLayout.ui"))

tmpform = uic.loadUi("customFormLayout1.ui"))
while tmpform.formLayout.count():
    customtab1.formLayout.addItem(tmpform.formLayout.takeAt(0))
```

This code is my attempt to add the contents of the first custom layout to the common one. It segfaults.

My question: why does it segfault and how should I be combining the two `QFormLayouts` into one? My experience with PyQt is limited.

Comment: It probably segfaults because you are not managing ownership of the objects properly. But why are you using separate ui files? It's hard to see what problem that would solve.

Comment: separate `ui` files because I do not want to duplicate the common part of the `ui` in two custom ones

Comment: I still don't see much value in having separate ui files. Personally, I only use Qt Designer for the static parts of the gui. The rest is all created dynamically at runtime. I suppose you could use widget promotion (or custom widgets) if your application has a lot of duplicated components: for more details on that, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22543079/984421), and [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using_Python_Custom_Widgets_in_Qt_Designer).