# Signals and Slots Editing Buttons Are Disabled (Qt Designer 4.8)

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt, qt-designer, signals-slots

I want to add custom slots to my design via Qt Designer (4.8), but editing buttons on "Configure Connection" window are disabled.  How can I solve it?

[image: signal and slot buttons are disabled on Qt Designer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add custom signals/slots to *subclasses* of Qt classes.

As a demonstration of this, make a connection between `pushButton` and the top-level widget. When the connection dialog is shown, you will see that the right-hand edit button is now enabled. This is because the top-level widget will usually be a subclass of `QWidget`, `QMainWindow`, or `QDialog` that is defined by the application.

To add custom signals/slots to *child* widgets, you would need to use [widget promotion](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets), so that you can specify a subclass that will be supplied by your application. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543079/984421) for how to promote widgets in PyQt.