# Signals/Slots Edit buttons are disabled in Qt designer

Tags: python, signals-slots, qt-designer

I'm new to Python. I'm studying Python on my own with books. I'm trying using Qt designer following a textbook.

## Problem

I can't click a button shown in the following picture. How can I enable the button? I need to set a custom slot named `buttonTalkSlot()`.

[image]

## What I did

I am sure I did as the textbook says.

1. Dragged and dropped **Push Button** and **List Widget** from Widget Box to MainWindow.
2. Changed the mode to Edit Signals/Slots.
3. Dragged and dropped from the push button to the list widget.
4. Configure Connection popped up, but the edit buttons are disabled.

## What I tried

I read the following answers, but I couldn't understand.

- [Replace QWidget objects at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528418/replace-qwidget-objects-at-runtime/22543079#22543079)
- [Signals and Slots Editing Buttons Are Disabled (Qt Designer 4.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084803/signals-and-slots-editing-buttons-are-disabled-qt-designer-4-8)

## My environment

- Mac OS (Version 10.14.6)
- Anaconda
- Qt designer (Version 5.9.7)

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't really make any sense, because the receiver isn't a user-defined subclass, so it cannot have any custom signals/slots. If the receiver was e.g. the main window or a promoted widget, the edit button *would* be enabled, since these must always be user-defined subclasses. But anyway, I think it's a mistake to try to create custom signals/slots via qt designer. It's a lot simpler to do all that in code, and also much easier to maintain in the long run (e.g. if you ever need to change the name/signature of a custom signal/slot).

Comment: @ekhumoro I am sorry I don't know I'm doing. I'm just following the book. So the book might be wrong.