# Add functionality to existing method of 3rd party library

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, overriding, qpushbutton

How would I add functionality to an existing method of a 3rd party object?

I am not sure if the question is expressed correctly, so here's an example of what I want to achieve.

The following function is used to blink a button:

```
def clickColor(button, color):
    beforeColor = button.palette().color(QPalette.Background)
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % color)
    QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: unClickColor(button, beforeColor))

def unClickColor(button, beforeColor):
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s" % beforeColor.name())
```

I want every QPushButton of the PyQt5 library to blink when it is clicked.

My thought is adding the clickColor function to the **clicked.connect** method of QPushButton, but keeping the existing method untouched.

What would be the right way to do what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom subclass and then use it instead of a normal `QPushButton` wherever you want the blink effect. If you're using Qt Designer, you can also use [widget promotion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) to replace any buttons added to the ui file with your custom class (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543079/984421) for more details).

Here is a basic demo script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class BlinkButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlinkButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.clicked.connect(self._blink)
        self._blink_color = QtGui.QColor()

    def blinkColor(self):
        return QtGui.QColor(self._blink_color)

    def setBlinkColor(self, color=None):
        self._blink_color = QtGui.QColor(color)

    def _blink(self):
        if self._blink_color.isValid():
            self.setStyleSheet(
                'background-color: %s' % self._blink_color.name())
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: self.setStyleSheet(''))

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = BlinkButton('Test', self)
        self.button.setBlinkColor('red')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)

    def handleButton(self):
        print('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```