# How to set the initial size of a QTreeView in a QSplitter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtreeview, qsplitter

I have a `QTreeView` inside of a `QSplitter` that I want to set the initial size of. I have found that I can set both `setMinimumWidth(val)` and `setFixedWidth(val)` on the `QTreeView`, but neither of those seem to do what I need.

The `setMinimumWidth(val)` only prevents the `QTreeView` from getting smaller than the value of `val`, and `setFixedWidth` prevents the user from resizing the `QTreeView` entirely.

Is there anyway to set the initial size, either by setting `QSplitter` or setting `QTreeView`? I assume I need to set the `sizeHint`, but I'm not quite sure.

I'm using Python 3 with PyQt5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reimplement `sizeHint` to set the initial size:

```
class TreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super().sizeHint()
        size.setWidth(320)
        return size
```

However, if creating a subclass is not desirable, and you don't mind setting a *proportional* initial size, you can use [QSplitter.setSizes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setSizes). The Qt docs define the behaviour of this method in this way:

> The overall size of the splitter widget is not affected. Instead, any
>   additional/missing space is distributed amongst the widgets **according
>   to the relative weight of the sizes**. [emphasis added]

So it doesn't matter if sum of the sizes is larger than the splitter; all that matters is the relative weights. Given this, we can just calculate the maximum possible size available, and then divide it up accordingly, like this:

```
width = QtWidgets.qApp.desktop().availableGeometry(self).width()
self.splitter.setSizes([width * 2/3, width * 1/3])
```

This will make the first widget twice as large as the second.

In addition to these approaches, you can also use [QSplitter.saveState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#saveState) and [QSplitter.restoreState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#restoreState) to save and restore the splitter sizes set by the user from a previous session.

**PS**:

If you're using Qt Designer, the above `sizeHint` approach can be used with widget promotion, which is quite simple to implement. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076247/984421) for an explanation of how to do this.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `sizeHint()` has not been implemented in a more straight forward manor such as `setSizeHint(width, height)` or something to that effect. I made the layout in Qt Creator, so subclassing would be undesirable, and I know that I can't use `setWidth(val)` directly on the `QTreeView`, but that method seems like the best option if I'm looking for an accurate size.

Comment: @AaronTomason. You can use widget promotion - see the update to my answer.

Comment: I think I will give widget promotion a spin. Thanks for the update!