# Promoting QListWidget in QtDesigner

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

For example, I have a project *Numerator* having two files:

- Numerator\program.py
- Numerator\Interface\paperCounter.ui

In the program.py I define a custom class *MouseTrackingList* based 
 on *QListWidget*. I use Qt Designer to generate user interface and to use it with *uic.loadUiType* in my *program.py*.

The problem is how to properly promote example QListWidget in Qt Designer. When I do right mouse click "promote to" and select name  of promoted class *MouseTrackingList* it automatically creates name of header file *mousetrackinglist.h*. Then I press "add" and "promote".

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054131/customising-code-of-qt-designer-widget) I see Header file must be the python import path for the module that contains this class. But I cannot understand where my mousetrackinglist.h is generated and how to import him in program.py.

Comment: Please read the answer more carefully. There is no header file. All you need to do is change *mousetrackinglist.h* in the Promote To dialog to the python package path where the `MouseTrackingList` class is located (e.g. "mypackage.program", or whatever). The correct import statement will be generated automatically.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got what you meant there.