# PyQt5: how to inherit a widget with its layout or geometry?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I put a QLineEdit in form.ui, and I want to use `CustomLabel` to inheriance it. But there are both 2 QLineEdit(`lines` in form.ui and `CustomLabel`) in my mainwindow.

How should I deal with this situation?

[Here is the image of my programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKlc1.png)

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import PyQt5.uic as uic


form_ui,_ =uic.loadUiType('form.ui')
print(type(form_ui))
class Mainwindow(QWidget,form_ui):
    """docstring for App"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        path_lineEdit = CustomLabel(self.lines)

class CustomLabel(QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(CustomLabel,self).__init__(parent)
        # self.resize(parent.size())

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        self.setText('212'+e.mimeData().text())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Mainwindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4: Replace QWidget objects at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528418/pyqt4-replace-qwidget-objects-at-runtime)

Comment: Thank you for your help!