# PyQt5 Validation on Focus change

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am writing a form using PyQt5.

I want the validation to work when the user switches inputs, if it is invalid it shows an error message and the focus is on the invalid textbox.

I've tried using the "editingFinished" to detect focus switching, but it doesn't work since if the validator is invalid it won't go into the "connected" function.

I've also tried making a custom LineEdit class, but I don't get how to make the LineEdit use my custom class, since I'm using a .ui file instead of a python script.

Any idea on how I could approach this?

Thanks

Comment: use a python script.

Comment: @Alexander i'm using Qt Designer for the interface, so I'd have to change the class manually everytime i'd regenerate the python file that's why it's out of the question for me

Comment: You can keep your logic in a separate file from ui. In fact that is the recommended approach.

Comment: @user21328155 You shall **never** edit those files. See how to properly [use Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @musicamante thanks, I've used "Promote to" to make it use custom classes [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528418/replace-qwidget-objects-at-runtime).